# Can we read straight from the Quran when we stand up for salat?

Tags: quran, salat, reading-quran

I believe salat is the practical implementation of the Quran. I have a handy booklet of Quran and I always want to read big Surats from the Quran when I stand up for prayers in Salat. My query is can we read straight from the Quran when we stand up for salat?

Comment: Thanks! What does Quran and Sunnah say about it? That is reciting Quran while you are in the state of Salat? I've heard it is only permitted while we perform Tarawees? May Allah forgive us...!

Answer (score 6):

Most scholars tend to say that it's acceptable to read from a Mushaf/Moshaf in Nafl (sunna) prayers like taraweeh/tarawih in Ramadan (of course if there's a hafidh/hafiz among the congregation it's preferable that he leads the prayer because of this [hadith](http://sunnah.com/bukhari/64/335)).

As an example um al mu'mminyn 'Aisha had a servant (slave?) as her imam in taraweeh prayer and he used to recite from a mushaf according to a commentary of Imam Malik and al-Bukhari who also [quoted](http://sunnah.com/malik/6/8) this narration! Unfortunatly sunnah.com has left out the corresponding commentary in the translation!

> قَالَ مَالِكٌ : " لَا بَأْسَ أَنْ يَؤُمَّ نَظَرًا مَنْ لَا يَحْفَظُ " .
>   Malik said: "There's nothing wrong to lead a prayer by looking (reading) for those who don't memorize (the qur'an)".

And al-Bayhaqi seem to have  quoted a similar narration!

But even those who say it's makruh to read from the Moshaf while praying fard/farz, say that the prayer would be valid. The only exception among Sunni scholars are the hanafis who seem to consider it invalid!

Here are two fatwas on the matter in [English](http://islamqa.info/en/65924) and [Arabic](http://fatwa.islamweb.net/fatwa/index.php?page=showfatwa&Option=FatwaId&Id=30209)!

And Allah knows best!

Comment: your second hadith of Aisha says "..used to stand in prayer and recite for her in Ramadan" . it doesn't say from a mushaf

Comment: @aadil095 "يَقْرَأُ لَهَا " in Arabic refers to reading not reciting! So the translation here is a bit misleading!

Answer (score 3):

I'm not aware of a reference in Quran or Hadith about this topic.

The prophet and his companions PBUH/T did learn the Quran by heart, so they haven't had this issue. If the Quran doesn't treat this matter it is of lesser ethical significance than halal/haram issues.

Now, if everyone did read off from the Quran, then who would want to learn it by heart? It is better to learn even a little, it is of honor to one's soul.

The closest Sunnah I can relate to this subject is the saying: "Ask your heart" from the prophet Mohammed PBUH.

Answer (score 1):

Assalamualaikum wr wb,

Salat is the time when you communicate with Allah swt. There's nothing between you and Allah at that time. Ones life should have the practical implementation of the Quran and sunnah. Salat is a part of it.

Consider something related to this duniya, assume that you are communicating something with a person who employed you for 10-15 years and paid you well beyond the market value for your skills. Would you show your appreciation to him by reading off of a book or by memorizing a few verses whose meaning you understand and can communicate well with?

I memorized many surats myself, i'm glad my parents made me, but as i grew up and Arabic not being the native language, I never understood how to communicate well.
I am asking my creator, should I not use the best choice of words for a situation, what and when i'm going to ask. We learn the tools of our trade and excel in it to make decent earnings but often fail to understand that Allah is the one who provides it. If you are here (this website) you must be a person from technology background. You were not born with a computer in your hand. you acquired the skill. Similarly one can definitely acquire the knowledge of Arabic language.

The questions here is not "can one read the quran while in salat", but, "should one?" Not every companion of the prophet Mohammed was a scholar. And although they spoke Arabic, they never read off of  quran during salat. (Per the scholar of my local masjid).

People will give you many opinions, but a smart person is one who learns effective communication.

and Allah knows best.

Answer (score 1):

I do with an intention to memorize the surahs and it has helped me. And motivates me to pray more... Honestly it should come from your heart Allah knows your intentions.

Comment: Welcome to Islam.SE! Please check out a [tour](https://islam.stackexchange.com/tour) of our site to learn more about how this site works. This answer could benefit from provided external sources to support your answer.

Answer (score 0):

If there is possibility to forget the verses, it might be valid during nafal prayer. Allah knows the best.

Comment: Answers should be elaborate and focused on addressing the question. Claims should be supported by evidence. Please visit our [tour] in the [help], and refer to [answer].

Answer (score 0):

Quran instructed us to recite from the Quran sura 73:20

And in sura 17:110 Allah swt instructed us that during prayer, not to recite too loudly nor too silent so what”s going on with our current salat
Allahu Alom