# Can a person who does not know to pray and what do the recitations reading off their phone/device?

Tags: salat, practical-islam, quran-recitation

If a person does not know how to pray and or is trying to learn a new Surah do so reading it off their phone during salat.

For example, if the person puts on a complete Salat tutorial with recitatons on YouTube or an App and recites along during the salat and performs the actions accordingly (sajood, etc.) or if the person does know how to pray but is learning a new Surah - can they have that Surah opened on their device, have it on the prayer mat in front and read it off that when they need to?

Or they must learn it before hand and cannot use their device?

Comment: Salam and welcome to IslamSE the Q&A site about Islam. Consider taking our [tour] and checking our [help] to learn more about our site and our model. As for the recitation or memorization the matter should already have been answered on the site.

Comment: Thanks will do. However would you also be able to point me to the correct post please?

Comment: See for example: [read memorized part of surah in prayer for repetition](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/47369/read-memorized-part-of-surah-in-prayer-for-repetition) and [Can we read straight from the Qur'an when we stand up for salat?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/17840/can-we-read-straight-from-the-quran-when-we-stand-up-for-salat)