# Looking and reciting quraan while praying

Tags: quran, salat, quran-recitation, taraweeh

So during this lockdown, for the taraweeh prayers, we had recited quraan during prayers by looking at it in phone keeping it in a stand by the side and praying. And now i wonder if that is really allowed or is it a sin?

Comment: [This](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/17840/can-we-read-straight-from-the-quran-when-we-stand-up-for-salat) actually answers your question.

Comment: thanks @Medi1Saif :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bin baz (late Saudi Mufti) , Mohamed almunajjed both said it's ok to read from The Qur'an and hold it while praying , Khaled Almosleh said the same for the Qura'an and for any tablets that shows the Qura'an.
May allah Accept your Salah

Comment: thanks brother :)